# VS 2010 Extensions -- Missing Structure Adornment & AllMargins plugins

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

I am rebuilding my DEV image and I am no longer able to find neither of these two great plugins on the VS Extensions Gallery: [Structure Adornment](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/203f22f4-3e9f-4dbb-befc-f2606835834e/), [AllMargins](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/465a0d53-5133-4edd-a0cd-94484fe3d853/)

Any ideas where did they go? Are there any replacements I can use? In the worst case, is it possible to extract **Structure Adornment** from my VS 2010 in my older image and install it into the new image?

Can't even imagine to go through thousands of lines of code without the nice vertical lines!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>According to [this blog post](http://dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-configure-allmargins-extension.html), AllMargins seems to have been superseded by Microsoft's own [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/).</s> Commenters have pointed out that this is not the case.

However, the free version of CodeRush ([CodeRush XPress](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/)) includes various [navigation features](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/navigation.xml) including *structural highlighting* (which I think is equivalent to *structure adornment*). Note that, despite the name, this extension requires a full (not Express) version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I haven't been able to get the Productivity Power Tools to display the vertical lines, and I also prefer the margin layout from AllMargins / OutlineMargin - does anyone know if I'm missing options to make the source map behave similarly, or some way of adding vertical drop lines as Structure Adornment used to do?

Comment: I agree with Ben here... Productivity Power Tools is really nice, but doesn't actually add all the features of AllMargins.  Structure Adornment specifically, does not seem to be a part of it. It would be nice if they wouldn't have un-published the extensions. And of course I can't find my old download of it :(

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've updated my answer with a better alternative.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge: CodeRush XPress seems to have the vertical lines within the source code, but not the vertical lines next to the scrollbar, which is IMO the core of the StructureAdornment. Do you know any other alternative?

Comment: @OregonGhost Sorry, not that I know of.

Answer (score 8):

I uninstalled AllMargins after installing the Productivity Power Tools, but then realized there were some features of AllMargins that I liked better. This led me on a hunt to find it again.  I had long since deleted my downloaded copy, and the official install has been removed from the VisualStudio Addons list.

However, I did find the source code still listed in Microsoft's archives, here:http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/OverviewMargin/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx

The file download is named "OverviewMargin.zip" on the page, but the actual file it links to is "AllMargins.zip", which contains all the source code. It shouldn't be too hard to build and install it from there.

Also, if you plan on trying to build it from source, you have to have the [VisualStudio 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=21835) installed first.

Finally, there is this old blog post on [how to configure AllMargins](http://dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-configure-allmargins-extension.html) in the registry.

---

*Edit:*

I also updated this plugin to work with VisualStudio 2012, and renamed it to "OverviewMargin2012" : [AllMargins / OverviewMargin extension updated to VisualStudio 2012](https://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/allmargins-overviewmargin-extension-updated-to-visualstudio-2012/)

Comment: This source seems to be a few versions older than what was available from the visual studio gallery. I have version 2.6 of the AllMargins extension, whereas the source is for version 2.3. Is there any later source code? I wonder why this extension was removed?

Comment: thank you so much for updating this extension for VS2012, it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party but since my Google search for AllMargins resulted in this page I figured I would update. Someone updated AllMargins to work with VS2012.

- [AllMargins 2012 @ Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/43bc4a3a-0182-4c36-8159-a0a4cdfd04bd).

It still works with VS 2010:

[image]

Comment: +1. This should be accepted answer. Name of the extension is deceiving, should be just called AllMargins.